# How to declare a class type with type aliases?

Tags: typescript

[**@type-challenges/utils.ts**](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/utils/index.d.ts)

```
export type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false

export type NotEqual<X, Y> = true extends Equal<X, Y> ? false : true
```

**Point.ts**

```
import { Equal } from '@type-challenges/utils'

class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {
    }
}

interface IPoint {

    prototype: {
        x: number,
        y: number
    };

    new(x: number, y: number): { x: number, y: number };
}

type TPoint =
    ( new (x: number, y: number) => {x: number, y: number} )
    |
    { prototype: {x: number, y: number}; };

type TPointProps = keyof typeof Point // "prototype"

type R1 = Equal<typeof Point, IPoint>; // true
type R2 = Equal<typeof Point, TPoint>; // false
type R3 = Equal<IPoint, TPoint>; // false
type R4 = typeof Point extends TPoint ? true : false; // true;
type R5 = TPoint extends typeof Point ? true : false; // false;
```

- `IPoint` equals to `typeof Point` as expected.
- But `TPoint` neither equals to `IPoint` nor `typeof Point`.
- More interesting, `typeof Point` extends `TPoint`, `TPoint` not extends `typeof Point`.

Am I missing something in `TPoint` to make it equal to `typeof Point`?

Comment: TypeScript interfaces' names should not start with `I`. TypeScript is not COM or .NET and a TypeScript structural interface is not directly comparable to a nominative interface.

Comment: Agreed. It's just for more easier to describe the question.

Comment: could you also share the `Equal` generic type?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik sure. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TPoint` is defined as having the `new` OR the `prototype` attributes. It's a union type.

While `typeof Point` has necessarily both, it's a sum type.

`A + B` is a subset of `A | B` but the reverse is not true.

If you want the sum type, you can write `TPoint` like this instead:

```js
type TPoint = {
    new(x: number, y: number): {x: number, y: number};
    prototype: {x: number, y: number};
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to declare `TPoint` as a `sum type` which equals to `typeof Point`?